# How to create custom selector for sitefinity related data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

Screenshot, I can't attach image directly:

[image: Screenshot, I can't attach image directly]

I want to filter the related data in selection window. I suppose it can be done with custom selector, but I can't find the example anywhere.

Comment: Hi Galang. can you provide more about your problem? what is our problem (data that you want to filter)? what custom that you want to add?

Comment: I think It's duplicated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210894/how-do-i-create-a-related-data-field-to-relate-to-another-age-in-a-sitefinity-cu