# How Do I create a related data field to relate to another age in a Sitefinity Custom Widget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, custom-widgets

I am creating custom widgets and custom designer views in sitefinity. How do a create a field, so the user can selected related data of type page?
I am using mvc and the latest version of Sitefinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a page selector in your custom designer view. 
These two articles should help:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-add-a-Page-selector-in-Feather-widgets-designer-view

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/page-selector-mvc